# How to return list of content from subquery for the main query?

Tags: mariadb, subquery

I have a create that have sub query. To show as example, here is a query that has similarity with my own. Personally I have more table and more arguments on table (The subquery have left join for example). I simplified it for the question.

```sql
SELECT
   Content,
   CASE 
      WHEN S.User IN (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Deleted = false) AND S.Permission Like '%ADMIN%' THEN 'Admin'
      ELSE 'Basic'
   END AS UserType,
   CASE 
      WHEN S.User IN (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Deleted = false) THEN 'Here'
      ELSE 'Not'
   END AS Exist
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Deleted = false
) as S;
```

I want to put the `SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Deleted = false` query into the main table as I'm using the result multiple times. In the example, I'm using the content 2 times. It's only for optimization. Hope it can really help performances.

I tried something like that:

```sql
SELECT
   Content,
   CASE 
      WHEN S.User IN (AvailableUsers) THEN 'Here'
      ELSE 'Not'
   END AS Exist,
   CASE 
      WHEN S.User IN (AvailableUsers) AND S.Permission Like '%ADMIN%' THEN 'Admin'
      ELSE 'Basic'
   END AS UserType
FROM (
   SELECT *, (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Deleted = false) as AvailableUsers
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Deleted = false
) as S;
```

But I get `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. How can I make as it works and run the query only one time?

PS: I don't have actual data as even me, while checking the query, wasn't looking for the data exactly.

Comment: Please add some data examples and expected result in text format. I think your queries can be written easily using LEFT JOIN

Comment: @ErgestBasha I understand why you want that, but a left join will not fit of what I want as it will be on the subquery and not the main one. For input/output data, I will try to give you one, but as it's sample things, my data is clearly different of that

Comment: Does  `MyTable` have a unique column ? You need something unique to force the subquery to return only one row . Something like *SELECT Content, (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Deleted = false AND MyTable.uniquecolumn=Users.something)*

Comment: That's the fact: both have unique column, but not in common, and I don't want to link them as the full `AvailableUsers` will be used in switch/case after it. Maybe the optimisation I'm trying to do isn't necessary, I'll more explain in the question

Comment: Try to avoid subqueries.  I don't understand your schema or what you are attempting to do, but I _think_ it could be achieved with a `FROM users JOIN mytable ON ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. I'm make the check on the query of `MyTable`, store as variable and use it. I'm doing like that:

```sql
SELECT
   Content,
   CASE 
      WHEN S.UserAvailable = 1 THEN 'Here'
      ELSE 'Not'
   END AS Exist,
   CASE 
      WHEN S.UserAvailable = 1 AND S.Permission Like '%ADMIN%' THEN 'Admin'
      ELSE 'Basic'
   END AS UserType
FROM (
   SELECT *,
      CASE
         WHEN User IN (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Deleted = false) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
      END AS UserAvailable
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Deleted = false
) as S;
```

Then it works, and I'm making the request only one time